# How to use CodeModel to invoke a method from a 2nd-level, abstract superclass?

Tags: java, code-generation, sun-codemodel

I am using CodeModel 2.6.

How would I generate this instruction, when the getType( ) method is inherited from an abstract superclass, two levels above the JDefinedClass?

```
    assertEquals(GeneraldocumenMetadata.TYPE, generaldocumenMetadata.getType());
```

Background:

1. The assertEquals(...) method comes from "import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;"
2. The class hierarchy is

   - GeneraldocumenMetadata extends ItemMetadata
   - ItemMetadata extends AbstractItemMetadata
   - AbstractItemMetadata owns the getType() method, and the private type field

The end-result/desired method is as follows:

```
@Test
public void testParameterizedConstructorSuccess()
{
    String modifiedType = GeneraldocumenMetadata.TYPE + "andMore";
    generaldocumenMetadata = new GeneraldocumenMetadata(modifiedType);

    assertEquals(modifiedType, generaldocumenMetadata.getType());
}
```

The CodeModel method looks like this at the moment, however "definedClass.getMethod("getType", new JType[] {}); " is returning null

```
private void testDefaultConstructorMethod(JFieldVar uutField, JVar staticTYPEVar, final JDefinedClass unitTestClass, JDefinedClass definedClass, JCodeModel codeModel)
{
    int modifiers = JMod.PUBLIC;

    JMethod unitTestMethod = unitTestClass.method(modifiers, Void.TYPE, "testDefaultConstructor");
    unitTestMethod.annotate(org.junit.Test.class);

    JBlock unitTestBody = unitTestMethod.body();

    unitTestBody.assign(uutField, JExpr._new(unitTestClass));
    JClass abstractItemMetadataClass = definedClass._extends();

    JMethod getTypeMethod = definedClass.getMethod("getType", new JType[] {});
    JExpr.invoke(getTypeMethod);

    JInvocation assertEqualsInvoke = codeModel.directClass("org.junit.Assert").staticInvoke("assertEquals").arg(staticTYPEVar).arg(JExpr.invoke(getTypeMethod));
    unitTestBody.add(assertEqualsInvoke);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke the method, instead of getting it as codeModel will not parse your defined class:

```
JExpr.invoke(uutField, "getType");
```

which means your codemodel code will look like the following:

```
private void testDefaultConstructorMethod(JFieldVar uutField, JVar staticTYPEVar, final JDefinedClass unitTestClass, JDefinedClass definedClass, JCodeModel codeModel)
{
    int modifiers = JMod.PUBLIC;

    JMethod unitTestMethod = unitTestClass.method(modifiers, Void.TYPE, "testDefaultConstructor");
    unitTestMethod.annotate(org.junit.Test.class);

    JBlock unitTestBody = unitTestMethod.body();

    unitTestBody.assign(uutField, JExpr._new(unitTestClass));
    JClass abstractItemMetadataClass = definedClass._extends();

    JInvocation assertEqualsInvoke = codeModel.ref(org.junit.Assert.class).staticInvoke("assertEquals").arg(staticTYPEVar).arg(JExpr.invoke(uutField, "getType"));
    unitTestBody.add(assertEqualsInvoke);
}
```